# spring data saving parent entity by first adding child to parent is resulting different references

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, cascade

I have these entities in my project for learning:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long ID;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addChild(Child child) {
       children.add(child);
       child.setParent(this);
   }

   // + getters/setters/constructor
}


@Entity
public class Child {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long ID;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
   private Parent parent;

   // + getters/setters/contructor
}
```

From outside (some frontend) I send request to create a new Child for given Parent. So that's how my Service looks like - method for creating child:

```
public Child createNewChild(String name, Parent parent) {
    Child child = new Child(name);
    parent.addChild(child);
    parentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);
    // List<Child> forTest = parent.getChildren();
    return child; // here, child.getID() = 0, bad. 
    // going deeper, child and the last element of forTest = references are not the same. The .getID() of this last element from forTest has correct ID
}
```

My repository is:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> { }
```

I don't know whether this is important but I use MySQL. Just for learning. I heard it is not the best choice.

My basic problem is that after this operation the `child` object is not getting refreshed ID value. So I began to think about it. I added that commented line above `parent.getChildren()` and I found in debugger that the last element of returned `List<Child>` - the `Child` object has appropriate ID and its reference is different than object `Child` where I create it.

Why? How to do it properly?